# How did a suggested edit get approved after two rejections?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I am confused as to how this suggested edit was marked "Approved".

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18035972

As per my knowledge (maybe wrong), edits by a user with 2k+ rep are instantly applied, but below 2k rep, the edit goes to review, where 3k+ rep users can look at it, and if 2 give approval, then the edit is considered as "approved", and the suggestion is closed.

[image]

But in this case 2 users rejected the suggestion 12 hours ago. So how did the question owner approve it 2 hours ago; after the two rejections, the suggestion should be cancelled.

Per my knowledge after 2 rejections or approvals, the suggested edit should disappear.

Comment: The OP approved the edit.

Comment: @George I know but how, before 12 hour that edit was rejected

Comment: It's not new that OP and mods can alter the review results of suggested edits.

Comment: Why is this down voted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Post owners and moderators can overrule an edit review. This has been implemented in [April 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/168333).